# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned error: oversized data when calling the set method for a very large cipher string

Tags: web3js, truffle, quorum

I am using a quorum 7 nodes example with IBFT genesis file. I have modified the **maxCodeSizeConfig to 128KB** (which is maximum). I have also increased the gas limit to 0x3B9AC9FFFFFF. But, when I am trying to call my setVariable(ciphertext).send() method, I am still getting the same error as **Oversized data** when calling the method.

Comment: Well, the `ciphertext` input to the method is data, not code. This is also obvious from the error-message that you're getting.

Comment: Yes, I tried adding the txnsizeLimit:128kb but I need to store the data of around **180kb.** How do we do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the transaction data size, not the code size. The transaction data size can be increased on Quorum with the genesis `txnSizeLimit` value (up to 128kb).

This is documented here: https://docs.goquorum.consensys.net/en/latest/HowTo/Configure/GenesisOptions/#configurable-transaction-size

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is 128kb the maximum txnSizeLimit? Because when I see the data size it is around 180 kb, how do we configure our genesis file for the same?

Comment: Yes, there is an upper limit of 128kb. Allowing excessively large transaction sizes isn't a good idea.
One workaround is to rewrite your smart contract to break down the transaction data into smaller units. Otherwise you would need to modify the code to allow a larger transaction size (not recommended).